# lightning:overlayLibrary popup window closing and opening

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am making a related list, that is filterable by certain criteria. I am developing a lightning component that i can use on Lightning Builder. In the component, i use `<lightning:overlayLibrary>` component to show a popup when users hovers a hoverable record link.

This is the picture of my current popup:
[image]

The problem i am facing, is opening and closing the popup correctly. Currently i am triggering a `onmousover event` on the **DIV** element and automatically close the event after 3 seconds. The **DIV** is the "**9999999**" as link on the left side of the picture.

Problems with that solution:

**1)** When user is going over the div not intentionally, the popup will show up because `onmouseover event` was triggered.

**2)** When user fastly drags the mouse over all the records in the related list, many popup's will show up, i have a check in my javascript that only 1 popup could be shown at once, but i am using `setTimeout()`.

**3** When users want to see the popup longer than 3 seconds, they have to reopen it. When i did not close the popup after 3 sec but used `onmouseleave` event, then when i go on the popup with my mouse, the popup will close, because the triggering div is this number **"999999"**

What i want to do, is Allow only 1 popup to be open, and if users leave the popup with the mouse, then the popup will be closed. Otherwise the popup will stay open.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Have to put a mouseenter event to the popover div?

Comment: I actually did not need this functionality when i analyzed business needs a bit deeper. But i got the solution for this, basically you would have to bind variable between the popup component and main component using `component.getReference()`, thisway you have bidirectional communication and it is easy to close/open the popup.